# Share data between html pages - angularJs

Tags: html, angularjs

I have page1.html has a list of objects, when the user clicks on one object the website should navigate to other page and display the object details.

1.HTML Page ahs a table , each row is object:

```
<tr ng-repeat="abjcet in nc.object">
           <td>{{object.title}}</td>
     </tr>
```

2.when user clicks on the title the same object must be transferred to the next HTML page and I've try this and I the object is retrieved but I don't know how to store it and use it in the next HTML page:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="object in nc.objects">
    <td ng-click="getById(object.id)">{{object.title}}</td>
</tr>
```

my Controller:

```
(function () {
    'user strict';

    angular.module('app').controller('myController', myController);

    myController.$inject = ['$http', '$scope' ];

 function myController($http , $scope ) {

         var nc = this;
         nc.objects = [];
         nc.object = null;

     nc.getById = getById ;

     init();


     function init(){
         getAll();

     }

     function getAll()
     {
         var url = "/getAll/";
         var Request = $http.get(url);
         Request.then(function (response) {

             nc.objects = response.data;

         });
     }

     function getById(id) {

         var url = "/findById/"+id;
         var Request = $http.get(url);
         Request.then(function (response) {

             nc.object = response.data;

         });
     }

}
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use localStorage if you need to navigate to another page, or use SPA (Single Page Application) with a service that shared your data across all your controllers.

```
// Save the title
localStorage.setItem('title', $scope.title);
// Retrieve the title
$scope.title = localStorage.getItem('title');
```

Answer (score 0):

If the HTML application of yours is `completely a single page application`, then add `$rootScope` to the `myController.$inject` and then save it in the `$rootScope`, which can be accessed across multiple pages.

Instead, if you have a `service` which is being used by both the controllers on different pages, implement `getters and setters` in the `service` for that variable.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: This is not the angular way, they actually advise you never to use `$rootScope` to maintain states of any kind. Events are the only thing `$rootScope` should be used for.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple solutions

1. Using Local storage, you can maintain that data and persist it across multiple pages, this is the safest and easiest approach. There's plenty of modules out this out of the box and do it well: [Angular local storage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage).

Example:

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, localStorageService) {
    // setter
    localStorageService.set('title', 'value');
    // getter
    var title = localStorageService.get('title');
});
```

2. [Routing](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)
   You can maintain data through a SPA (Single Page Application) using Routes, this stops the browser from actually reloading the page, and allows the user to just request the next view/page. This means that you can save the data inside a factory for example, and the data will be maintained in internal memory.

Example:

```
//factory
myApp.factory('Data', function() {
    var data = {};
    return {
        get :get,
        set : set
    };
    // setter
    function set(key, val){
        data[key] = val;
    }
    // getter
    function get(key) {
        return data[key] || null;
    }
});

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function(Data) {
    // setter
    Data.set('title', 'value');
    // getter
    var title = Data.get('title');
});
```